# How to extract heading numbers from a document using python-docx?

Tags: python, parsing, ms-word, python-docx

I'm using python-docx library to extract data from a docx document, however I also want the heading number/ paragraph number. I want to build a build a proof reading tool for which I need to know that information, however **I can neither find that information in the text, nor the style of the paragraph**. Is there some way to extract that information?
I can just loop through the tags of same heading number, but what if the user didn't use proper heading tags while writing the document?
Or what if they choose to not use the default word convention of `1, 1.1, 1.1.1, a` and choose to use something of their own instead?

[image: Default convention]

Basically I want a way to extract these numbers, `2, 2.1, 2.2.1, (a)`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that python-docx has no function to extract number headings so I created it, see in my github: https://github.com/nguyendangson/extract_number_heading_python-docx

Input: your docx path

Output: a list of number and name headings.

```
def extract_number_heading(doc_path: str):
'''
Input: path of a docx file 
Output: a list of heading names and their number headings corresponding chapters, sections, subsections,... 
'''
doc = Document(doc_path)
# Extract chapters, section, subsection numbers
heading_numbers=[]
heading_name=[]

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    # Check if the paragraph is a heading
    if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'):            # Heading for all chapters, sections, subsections,.., Heading 1 for chapter, Heading 2 for subsections, Heading 3 for subsubsections
        # Save heading numbers and heading names      
        heading_numbers.append(paragraph.style.name.split()[1])
        heading_name.append((paragraph.text))
#print(heading_numbers)

# Map heading_numbers to heading sections
heading_sections_result = []
chapter = 1
for i in range(len(heading_numbers)):
    if heading_numbers[i] =='1':
        heading_sections_result.append(str(chapter))
        chapter+=1
    else:
        if int(heading_numbers[i]) > int(heading_numbers[i-1]):

            if int(heading_numbers[i]) == 2:
                heading_sections_result.append(heading_sections_result[-1]+'.1')
            else:
                heading_sections_result.append(heading_sections_result[-1] + '.1'*(int(heading_numbers[i])-2))


        elif int(heading_numbers[i]) == int(heading_numbers[i-1]):
            u = heading_sections_result[-1].split('.')
            u[-1] = str(int(u[-1])+1)
            heading_sections_result.append('.'.join(u))
   
        elif int(heading_numbers[i]) < int(heading_numbers[i-1]):
            u = heading_sections_result[-1].split('.')
            u = u[:int(heading_numbers[i])]
            u[-1] = str(int(u[-1])+1)
            heading_sections_result.append('.'.join(u))

# Combine heading_name and heading_sections_result 
total_heading = []
for i in range(len(heading_numbers)):
    total_heading.append(heading_sections_result[i] + ' ' + heading_name[i])


return total_heading
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar one but for multilanguage.

Firstly you have to observe the heading(1, 2, 3 ..) and subheading (2.1, 2.2 ..) and try to extract some common things. They might have some of the below unique patterns:

1. Bold text
2. Font, size
3. Headings start with int(2) and subheadings with float (2.1)
4. What is the delimiter ('\t' or 'space') before the text and after the number

Observe these things and try to frame the pattern. By using the regex, we can extract the required.

Here is the regex, which will satisfy your case. Even for multi-language.

```
headings = regex.search("\d+\.\t(\p{Lu}+([\s]+)?)+")
subHeadings =regex.search("\d+\.\d+\t\p{Lu}(\p{Ll}+)+")
```

The python regex ( re ) is not backward compatible. So use this [regex][1] especially if your text is multi-language.

```
import regex
from docx import Document
doc = Document("<<Your doc file name here>>")

# Iterate through paragraphs ( in a word everything is a paragraph)
# Even the blank lines are paragraphs
for index, para in enumerate(doc.paragraphs):

# Skipping the blank paragraphs
    if(para.text):
        headings = regex.search("\d+\.\t(\p{Lu}+([\s]+)?)+",para.text,regex.UNICODE)
        subHeadings = regex.search("\d+\.\d+\t\p{Lu}(\p{Ll}+)+",para.text,regex.UNICODE)
        if headings:
            if para.runs:
                for run in para.runs:
                    # At run level checking for bold or italic.
                    if run.bold:
                        print("Bold Heading :",headings.group(0))
                    if run.italic:
                        print("Italic Heading :",headings.group(0))
          if subHeadings :
            if para.runs:
                for run in para.runs:
                    # At run level checking for bold or italic.
                    if run.bold:
                        print("Bold subHeadings :",subHeadings .group(0))
                    if run.italic:
                        print("Italic subHeadings :",subHeadings .group(0))
```

**Note:** The Bold or Italic will not always be there at the run level. If you are not getting these parameters, you should check in style and para level.